# How can I set just `Widget` size?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

How can I set just `Widget` size?

My code:

```
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
import sys
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

mainWindow = QWidget()
gameWidget = QWidget(mainWindow)

#gameWidget.setGeometry(gameWidth, gameHeight) <-- I want to set size of gameWidget such like this. How can I do this.
gameWidget.move(100,0)
gameLabel = QLabel("This is game widget", gameWidget)

mainWindow.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Description:

This will create `Window` that contain `Widget`.
I want to set this `Widget` size. I know There is a method `Widget.setGeometry`, but it takes 4 parameter  *(x, y, width, height)*. I want a method like `Widget.setGeometry` which takes just size parameter *(width, height)*.

**P.S.**
Feel free to modify my question. Because I'm always learning English!!

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on what you want to have in the end using a layout (`QLayout` derived) might be a very comfortable way to automatically have widgets of the right size.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use [`QWidget.resize(width, height)`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.resize). This is equivalent to `QWidget.resize(PySide.QtCore.QSize(width, height))`.

For example:

```
gameLabel.resize(200, 100);
```

---

Besides, you can also use [`QWidget.sizeHint()`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.sizeHint) to get a proper size automatically, for example:

```
gameLabel.resize(gameLabel.sizeHint());
```

Comment: It worked. And Additional info about `sizeHint` seems very helpful. Thanks so much.

Comment: To add to @Tay2510's answer. You could use [SizePolicy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop).